# SwiftUI Preview Buttons in pressed state

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'am trying to preview buttons in pressed state but don't know how to achieve this.
I don't want to store a variable only used for preview in the view or in the model. I can't find a way to simulate configuration.ispressed true for the preview, maybe it's impossible ?
Following is my actual code:

The View:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct TextButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TextButtonModel
    
    public init(model: TextButtonModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            TextView(model: model.textModel)
        }
        .buttonStyle(ButtonViewStyle(model: model))
    }
}
```

The Style:

```
import Foundation

import SwiftUI

struct ButtonViewStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let model: ButtonModel

    @ViewBuilder
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(EdgeInsets(uiEdgeInsets: model.getPadding()))
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .background(model.getBackgroundColor(isPressed: configuration.isPressed))
            .cornerRadius(999)
    }
}
```

And my preview:

```
#Preview {
    return VStack {
        HStack {
            TextButtonView(model: TextButtonModel(textModel: TextModel(text: "Body", color: Color.White, fontSize: FontSize.Body, fontWeight: .Semibold), color: Color.Primary, type: ButtonType.Filled, size: ButtonSize.Normal))
            TextButtonView(model: TextButtonModel(textModel: TextModel(text: "Subheadline", color: Color.White, fontSize: FontSize.Body, fontWeight: .Semibold), color: Color.Primary, type: ButtonType.Filled, size: ButtonSize.Small))
            TextButtonView(model: TextButtonModel(textModel: TextModel(text: "Body", color: Color.White,fontSize: FontSize.Body, fontWeight: .Semibold), color: Color.Primary, type: ButtonType.Filled, size: ButtonSize.Large))
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

User action is something you can mock with XCUITest framework. Xcode Preview is not designed for that.

> I don't want to store a variable only used for preview in the view or in the model

You don't need to store a variable in the `view` or the `view model`, but you need to have an override point in the `style` like:

```
struct ButtonViewStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var forcePressed = false //  default value will opt out the need to pass it everywhere

    @ViewBuilder
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .background(forcePressed || configuration.isPressed ? .red : .blue) //  force the style if needed
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```

And it will be used as simple as:

```
ContentView()
    .buttonStyle(ButtonViewStyle(forcePressed: true))
```

<sub>Note how you should round the corners to have a `capsule` shape design</sub>